# How to client-side routing url that ends with file extension

Tags: javascript

Say a user gives the title of a note as 'onboarding.md'.

And the url ends up like this `localhost:4000/ecme/onboarding.md`.

Now upon a refresh with that url, I want my **client-side router** to handle it - load a component, calls an api via fetch, then loads the result into the component.

But I get a blank page with an error `Cannot GET /ecme/onboarding.md`.

No such error if I programmatically navigate to the note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not really.

If the user is refreshing the page then the browser is asking the server for that URL.

Your client-side router hasn't even been loaded.

---

When you use client-side routing with "real" URLs (as opposed to hash-routing where all the route data is kept in the fragment identifier) then you **must have server-support too**.

Good router support would use server-side rendering so the page would be delivered complete from the server instead of being generated client side. This is efficient (no need to serve a bootstrap page and then have the client do all the work and making additional HTTP requests for data), search engine friendly, and means that if JS fails [for any reason](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) then the page will still be accessible.

There are frameworks to support this for most common SPA frameworks (e.g. React has Next.js).

---

The quick and dirty approach if you want to around SSR is to just configure the server to serve up the bootstrap HTML document that runs the client-side code for every URL it is asked for (or at least those not associated with a file). This doesn't have the benefits listed above and also ends up giving clients (including search engines) an HTML document even whey they should get a 404 Not Found error.